# Sending Parameters to onPostExecute in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, parameter-passing

onPostExecute is going to use 2 Parameters,
GCMID from the doInBackground
and UserID from the main function where AsyncTask was called

I tried to change the parameters in the declaration of the AsyncTask but I got error "attempt to use incompatible return type"

```
String UserID = "Admin";
new GCM().execute(null,null,null);
```

---

```
    private class GCM extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String[]  doInBackground(String... params) {
            String gcmRegID = GHelper.GCMRegister("123456");
            return gcmRegID;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String RegID) {
            UTask ut = new UTask();

            // ****** I managed to send RegID
            // ****** I can not send UserID !! How to send it?

            ut.execute(UserID, RegID);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have 3 null parameters to your AsyncTask execute?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
String UserID = "Admin";
new GCM().execute(null,null,null);
```

And

```
private class GCM extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {

    @Override
    protected String[]  doInBackground(String... params) {
        String regId = somethingToGetRegId();
        String userId = somethingToGetUserId();
        return new String[]{regId, userId};
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] values) {
        UTask ut = new UTask();

        String regId = values[0];
        String userId = values[1];
        ut.execute(UserID, RegID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can send UserId though GCM constructor.

```
private class GCM extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
  private String userId;
  public GCM(String UserId){
     this.userId=UserId;
  }
```

and than in 'onPostExecute()' you can use it like that:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String RegID) {
        UTask ut = new UTask();
        ut.execute(this.userId, RegID);
    }
```

And use it like so

```
new GCM(UserId).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change,

```
@Override
        protected String[]  doInBackground(String... params) {
            String gcmRegID = GHelper.GCMRegister("123456");
            return gcmRegID;
        }
```

to

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String gcmRegID = GHelper.GCMRegister("123456");
            return gcmRegID;
        }
```

You're return type is String[] and you are returning a String in doInBackground().